# Running a Python script from Java and passing user input

Tags: java, python

I have a simple **Python** desktop program that gets input data from the user at run time.
Here's an execution example:

```
$ python3 updatedatabase.py
Insert your name:
> John
Insert your surname:
> Smith
Insert your email:
> johnsmith@mail.com
Your entry has been inserted in the database!
```

I'm writing a **Java application** that is supposed to **use that Python** program with a graphical interface. So when I get all required parameters from the user, I have several attributes filled with name, surname and email. How can I execute the Python script and pass to it the 3 fields?

I found only answers where parameters are being passed as arguments of the Python script (e.g. `$ python3 updatedatabase.py John Smith johnsmith@mail.com`).

Notice that I am not allowed to edit anyhow the Python program.

**The real problem**

So that was a "toy example" to show my issue. I am actually writing a Spring Boot web application that will eventually use that Python program. I don't want the Python program to be running on my server unless required by the user. Moreover as it's mostly a one-way communication I was hoping there was a more straightforward way to pass those strings (than using IPC primitives). Also considering that they totally look like arguments (if only the Python program was written differently).

Comment: You should show your effort in trying to do solve the problem. Some basic search on how to execute commands from the command line is enough to get you started.

Comment: is there any reason you're going with "trying to make java run python" instead of having the python program running, ready to receive instructions, having your java program running, ready to issue instructions, and having them talk to each other using any of quite a few communication/API protocols? E.g. sockets, pipes, file polling, rpc, xml/json-over-http API, etc. etc. etc?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for your comment. I hope I managed to better explain the issue in my original post

Comment: Always better not to first posit a toy example and then the real one: just describe the real one in a concise manner, and then you don't end up spending time writing edits or clarifications later.

Comment: I think @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans makes a good point. Describing the "real" problem also helps avoid cases of the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/628382).

Comment: You can't modify the Python program at all? If that's the case, then we're going to need far more information on how it functions.

Comment: @AMC thanks as well for the comment. Unfortunately I can't edit the Python program as it's a requirement of the application I've been asked to make by my professor. About your second request, I assure you that the program is matching my example: it displays output asking for a string, once it gets the first input it goes one with the second question and so on. At last it collects all the answers to run a more complex job (whose purpose I'm not required to know).

Comment: Ah, well that's too bad. You're going to have to feed the input to stdin.

Comment: If this is a homework assignment, please explain that in your post, because the answers for homework are almost always code that is either super inefficient, or even downright bad code in the real world, which is "fine" because it's not meant to teach you an implementation, but a programming concept. Not saying something is homework, though, gets you comments like mine - as homework, there is zero reason to do anything other than [spawning a process](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String[])) and directly hooking into the in/output streams

Answer (score 0):

You can launch your Python Script with something like this

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python3 updatedatabase.py");
```

And then use the [Process#getOutputStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream--) method to get a stream to your Python script and use it to write your fields. (Using a [PrintStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) for example)